# Is it a good practice to have config in Redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've seen someone else's app and found out that he was having client config stored in Redux store. It mostly contained information like: isProduction: true, API keys etc.

What's your opinion about this? Do you consider it a good practice to have a config saved in Redux store?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, these keys/flags should be stored as constants/config and separated completely from redux. I store only things that are state of the running app in the store, either UI state or internal BL state.

Comment: Store is place to __save all the data which changes by user interactions__. When the data on the store change the components listening on the store will also re-render. 


So having the __data which never changes__ on the store is a __bad idea.__ Its better to have then on a constant file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, in application state, you store data that changes when a user interacts with the app. (as [Anenth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2686105/anenth) noticed). If you use webpack I would recommend you to store env variables and other configurations in webpack config file using [DefinePlugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#defineplugin)

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(true),
    VERSION: JSON.stringify("5fa3b9"),
    BROWSER_SUPPORTS_HTML5: true,
    TWO: "1+1",
    "typeof window": JSON.stringify("object")
})
```

Or [ExtendedDefinePlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extended-define-webpack-plugin) if you need more complex data structure.